# How can you update a textarea's value dynamically while still being able to edit it - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, textarea

I have a `textarea` with an `onChange` handler:

```
onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
}
```

but I also want to be able to set the `value` attribute dynamically based on data from MongoDB. It is for a diary app so the idea is that it looks for entries by setting `value={this.displayEntry()}`. Trouble is, I can't type in the `textarea` because every time I enter a key the `onChange` fires and the `value` is preset to whatever came from MongoDB or empty string.

Function for adding code from MongoDB (`journal` comes from Redux)

```
displayEntry() {
    const { todaysDate } = this.state;
    const { journal } = this.props;
    if (journal) {
        for (let entry of journal.data.entries) {
            if (entry.date === todaysDate) {
                return entry.content;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
    return "";
}
```

I hope it's clear what I want to achieve. Is there a way round this problem?

Comment: Please add the code where you update the value from MongoDb. I think the problem is there.

Comment: I've added the function that gets the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must initialise the state from the redux data only once. Then you can continue to edit it.

For example (lets suppose that the name of your text area is journal):

```
onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
}

getEntry() {
    const { todaysDate } = this.state;
    const { journal } = this.props;
    if (journal) {
        for (let entry of journal.data.entries) {
            if (entry.date === todaysDate) {
                return entry.content;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
    return "";
}

componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({
        journal: getEntry()
    });
}

// in render
<textarea value={this.state.journal} onChange={this.onChange} />
```

Comment: Do you mean that I shouldn't use the onChange handler?

Comment: You must keep it.

Comment: This doesn't work since the journal data is not returned from MongoDB before the component renders

Comment: Then wait until the data is arrived from the database and you render this component just then. You can display a ProgressBar until then.

Comment: This worked when I also set state journal: getEntry() in the date change functions. Thanks a lot :)